# Is it possible to use normal map as a mask while mixing shaders?

Tags: normal-map, masking

If I have a normal map that adds scratches to a surface and I want to add some dirt inside these scratches can I somehow use the normal map as a mask while mixing two shaders or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: We'd need to see the normal map to say how best to do it.

Comment: I think it's possible to designate a color spectrum in a node (to make it a factor of a Mix Shader), don't remember with what node though